# Google Wave Server Installation

Tags: google-wave, openfire

I am trying to install a google wave server on a linux virtual machine as local host.  I followed all the instructions given on the wave-protocol installation wiki http://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/wiki/Installation  but i'm getting this error when I run the run-server.sh script.

**$ ./run-server.sh
Jul 23, 2010 10:02:24 AM org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.waveserver.WaveServerImpl 
INFO: Wave Server configured to host local domains: [muranaka-desktop]
Jul 23, 2010 10:02:24 AM org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.waveserver.WaveServerImpl 
SEVERE: Failed to add our own signer info to the certificate store
org.waveprotocol.wave.crypto.SignatureException: Certificate validation failure**

couldn't connect to XMPP server:org.xmpp.component.ComponentException: conflict
Jul 23, 2010 10:02:25 AM org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.ServerMain run
INFO: Starting server
Jul 23, 2010 10:02:25 AM org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.ServerMain main
SEVERE: IOException when running server: Address already in use

In the run-config.sh script i set the hostname to my host name and domain name to localhost.  But I cant seem to get passed the certificate issue.  I used the generate self signed certificates script provided on the wiki to generate my certificates but it doesn't work. is it because im using a localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out openfire current version has a bug.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually skip tests and build the actual product just by running:

```
ant compile-gwt
ant dist-server
```

( Faced the same problem, but this page saved the day: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-wave-dev/201109.mbox/%3CCADgFs893OjBcGqJRqXFzkxHZU6wnEfoPDXjXutK6_oasSJOjOg@mail.gmail.com%3E )

Hope it helped